# Failure of getting Kernel trace logs

Tags: linux-kernel, trace

"File possibly truncated. Need atleast %ld size but size is %ld". How is this message is invoked?  I am seeing this message when I am trying to collect the kernel-trace. Can anyone explain why this scenario occurs when I am trying to collect the kernel-trace?

Comment: Can anybody help me out as soon as possible....